# Working with many landsat files and separating into lists by date

Tags: r, filenames, r-raster, landsat

So I have about 1000 landsat files of all the bands for different dates from 1980s to present. Overall I'm trying to create a time series of NDVI but at the moment I'm just trying to separate out the files by date and in a way which I can use them in calculations

I've used this code to separate the files by the date and it's worked

```
#splits files into groups by date
d <- sub(".*_([0-9]{8}_[0-9]{8}).*", "\\1", all_landsat_bands)
dates <- split(all_landsat_bands, d)
dates
```

I get an output looking like this:

[output from file separation by date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6InYg.png)

What I'm struggling with is completing calculations using the bands within the separated groups.

I tried getting one band for example band 3

```
date <- dates["19901119_20211122"]
date[3]
```

but I just get `$<NA> NULL`

Comment: Please edit your question and add a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example*.